# React app not deploying to a shared hosting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-deployment

Good evening everyone. Please I really need help deploying a react app which has been driving me crazy for the past 2 days. I specified in the package.json the homepage field and I ran **yarn run build**.
[image: preview]
I uploaded the build file to my shared hosting (cPanel) and open the website and its showing me **403 forbidden** with the react logo at the title field showing that it actually read the index.html.
Please I really really need help. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: The favicon being displayed does not mean that your app is being run. If there is a `favicon.ico` file in the root, it will usually load automatically.

Comment: Where exactly did you upload the files to? What folder?

Comment: to the public_html sir

Comment: you might want to contact your hosting provider in that case. Perhaps your .htaccess file is misconfigured

Answer (score 0):

You may want to tend to the flags and errors during your build. so you'd be sure the break is not from your side. Feel free to go through this five minutes read on cpanel deployment [here](https://dev.to/crishanks/deploy-host-your-react-app-with-cpanel-in-under-5-minutes-4mf6)